# Pass the value of a HTML input to a Livewire component?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a button and a hidden input. When I click the button, I need the hidden input value to be passed to a Livewire component with the `wire:click` method. I have done this code so far but it has some bugs like only working correctly in the 2 time I click the button.

**View**

```php
<input name="{{ $parameter->id }}" id="{{ $parameter->id }}" 
       value="{{ json_encode($parameter->value) ?? ''}}">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="manage-{{$parameter->id}}" 
    wire:click="">
    {{ __('cbs::topics.create.parameters.list.manage-'. $parameter->type .'s') }}
</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#manage-{{$parameter->id}}').setAttribute('wire:click', "$emitTo('topic-parameter-files-modal', 'loadModal', {{$parameter->id}}, '{{$parameter->type}}', '" + document.getElementById({{$parameter->id}}).value + "')");
            $('#manage-{{$parameter->id}}').click(function(){
                $(this).setAttribute('wire:click', "$emitTo('topic-parameter-files-modal', 'loadModal', {{$parameter->id}}, '{{$parameter->type}}', '" + document.getElementById({{$parameter->id}}).value + "')");
});
```

Comment: but this is in the blade rendered by the component??? why are you using JS for this basic Livewire behavior???

Comment: Just pass the hidden value as an argument to `wire:click`, so that you don't have a hidden input at all. You don't really need any JS/jQuery to achieve this, that's just making it more complex than it needs to be :)

Comment: This is not in the blade rendered by the component, this is the blade which has a button for a file upload moda (CRUD Create)l, and I have a hidden input in the blade that stores the files array for Objects that have not been created. This array is always being updated from a listener and passed the value to the hidden input

Comment: It looks like you may need to share more of the process that happening here as it's not totally clear why you're setting your `wire:click` with javascript. Either way I'd probably avoid using jQuery and instead use AlpineJs. You'll be able to do everything you'd want to with Alpine and it's made to work well with Livewire 

Answer (score 0):

This is was what I did.
I used form

**Form Attributes**

```
id='somename' wire:submit.prevent=''
```

**Javascript**

```
    document.getElementById('somename').setAttribute('wire:submit.prevent', 'what I want to pass')
```

**Updated: You can use emit on it. **

Found out that the form lose the attribute value.

```
document.getElementById('somename').setAttribute('wire:submit.prevent', '$emit('event', 'what you want to pass')

document.getElementById('somename').addEventListener('submit', () => {
            document.getElementById('some').setAttribute('wire:submit.prevent', "$emit('event','what you want to pass')")
        })
```